# how to upate multiple rows with one single SQL statement, each to a different status

Tags: sql, mysql

Say I have this two-column table

```
 id  | column_test

 1   | NULL

 2   | NULL

 3   | NULL
```

...

as you see, the column_test column now all have value 'NULL'. Now I want to do an update to this table and the final status should look like :

```
 id  | column_test

 1   | a

 2   | b

 3   | c
```

...

I know little about compound SQL statements, it looks the query to be used is a small SQL program which is probably going to have local variables involved. Unfortunately I don't know the exact syntax yet(I've tried to build the query myself in the last 20-30 minutes), maybe I can find some SQL gurus here to help me out.-)

[edit:let's stick to mysql.]

Comment: Where do the values come from that you want to use to update or are they actuaaly a for 1, b for 2?

Comment: Please add some informationa about the RDBMS/database you want to use.

Comment: @astander : it's simply 'a' then 'b' then 'c' ... 
@IronGoofy : I'm on mysql, couldn't it be a general SQL question ?

Comment: `@Shawn`: no, `SQL` syntax you want is not portable.

Comment: How many rows do you have? What to do after ~25 when you reach 'z'?

Comment: @IronGoofy: We'll pretend it's less than 25 now, that's my key problem here, as much as the question title indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MySQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT NOT NULL, column_test CHAR(1));

INSERT
INTO    mytable (id)
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  mytable
SET     column_test = CHAR(96 + (@r := @r + 1))
WHERE   column_test IS NULL
ORDER BY
        id;

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable;
```

In `SQL Server`:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   column_test IS NULL
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     column_test = CHAR(96 + rn)
```

Comment: Because the id's can be not consecutive.

Comment: Tried MySQL query, it sets the column values to empty(not null).

Comment: Incorrect string value : '\C7' for 'column_test' at row 1
Incorrect string value : '\C8' for 'column_test' at row 2
Incorrect string value : '\C9' for 'column_test' at row 3
Incorrect string value : '\CA' for 'column_test' at row 4
sorry but is this related to my charset which is UTF-8.

Comment: `C7` is `199` which is far beyond the alphabet range `(97 - 122)`. This means you have at least `104` items. Seems pretending that there are mo more than `25` records helps no more and you need to define what to do after the `Z`.

Comment: Or maybe your forgot to reset `@r`. Did you issue `SET @r := 0` before issuing the query?

Comment: `@Shawn`: could you please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`?

Comment: 'mytable', 'CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `column_test` char(1) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: Which version of `MySQL` are you using?

Comment: @Quassnoi: mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45, for win32<ia32>

Comment: Just checked it on `5.0`, works fine, the connection charset and the database charset are both set to `UTF-8`. Did you copy the script word-to-word and paste it?

Comment: yes. Thanks though I'll try it over again. Thanks for your patience. Will update later.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can set the column to a function-result of some other columns and therefore set different rows to different values. One example:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column_test = cola+colb/colc
```

Closer to your question, this should work

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column_test = Char (ASCII('a') + id-1)
```

Of course this would only work for a limited number of rows in your table.